# DBT Stripe Package, Schema Duplication in Snowflake

Tags: stripe-payments, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt, fivetran

I am using the following DBT Package provided by Fivetran:
https://hub.getdbt.com/fivetran/stripe/latest/

When the models are processed using `dbt run` we duplicate the schemas in snowflake:

- Stripe
- Stripe combined data

1. `stripe_combined` is how we named the schema in dbt_project.yml
2. But once the operation is processed it seems to create an additional Schema titled `Stripe` with the exact same data in snowflake

One thing to note is that in our model's section in dbt_project we state the schema name

```
 stripe:
    materialized: table
    +schema: stripe_combined
```

Comment: I'd recommend working directly with Fivetran for help on how to configure their connector here. You could also look at Stripe's own solution for Snowflake which they built recently in https://www.snowflake.com/datasets/stripe-stripe-data-pipeline/

Comment: @Solomon, do you have any custom source defined? Such as mentioned here? [Define your Database and Schema vars](https://github.com/fivetran/dbt_stripe_source#step-3-define-database-and-schema-variables)